# Sencha Touch [APPNAME].app is undefined only when testing with Jasmine

Tags: testing, extjs, jasmine, sencha-touch, global-variables

I'm trying to set up some test cases for a view using the Jasmine 2.3.4 assertion library for my Sencha Touch 2.4 app. Things seem great (I see the view rendered to a div) except the browser does not know what `MyApp.app` is. I have this line at my `onContainerInitialize` function from my view/container code:

```
var controller = MyApp.app.getController('loginController');
```

which gives this Jasmine error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getController' of undefined
```

At the time the Jasmine tests are called, from my console I do have a `MyApp` global object with the following structure (attached). If you expand `app` you will see the class name of the controller listed in an array under `_controllers`. The line that causes this error in my spec file is:

```
var myView = new MyApp.view.someViewName({ renderTo: 'test' });
```

I modeled my setup after a few tutorials, one of which is Sencha's https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/guide/testing
(wish there was one for a recent version of Touch). I think my problem may be related to this note midway down that page:

> Note: this Application definition is not a copy and paste of your
>   regular Application definition in your app.js. This version will only
>   include the controllers, stores, models, etc and when launch is called
>   it will invoke the Jasmine tests.

It may be related, but I also couldn't follow their:

```
ctrl = newMyApp.controller.MyController();
```

where I would get this error:

```
TypeError: app.getRouter is not a function at Ext.define.applyRoutes (http://localhost:8080/touch/sencha-t...ug.js:45800:26)
```

Instead, I had to add in this argument like this:

```
var ctrl = new Kaacoo.controller.loginController({ application : app });
```

Additionally, my launch file is set up like this:

```
Ext.require('Ext.app.Application');

Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true,
    disableCaching: true
});

Ext.Loader.setPath('MyApp', '../../app');
// this file is a couple levels deep from the root of my project

Ext.application({
    name : 'MyApp',
    extend: 'MyApp.Application',
    autoCreateViewport: true,
    controllers: [
        'loginController'
    ],

    requires : [
    ],

    launch: function() {
        // Jasmine is bootstrapped with boot.js referenced in the html runner, so nothing here. My test specs are being called after this launch function is executed. 
    }
});
```

The order I have listed my resources in my html runner are: Jasmine Library with boot.js> Touch All Debug Library > Project Source Files > Spec Files > Launch file

Building and simulating the app is fine, so why can't I also have access to MyApp.app.getController('loginController') as well in my test environment?

Thanks!